# How to bundle a redirect & render response together in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am writing a Symfony2 controller. My controller deletes a user and then displays a success or failure message. This is working and the response looks like:

```
return $app['twig']->render('index.twig', array('list' => $list,'msg' => $msg));
```

There is one issue. The website lands on `index/{username}/`. I would like the website to instead land on `index/` and display the message there. I am able to redirect with the following response:

```
return new RedirectResponse('/index/users/');
```

The question is how do I bundle together both responses, so I redirect to `index/` and also display the message there?

Comment: If you use Annotations, Templates & Configuration/Routes  no need to do all this extra lines of code.  Check here  http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bundle 2 different responses together... the controller MUST return a Response object of some sort... and only one...

you best solution would be to take advantage of flash messages... You can store your message in the [flashbag](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#flash-messages) (which is basically the session) then view it on the "index" after you have been redirected...they are called flash because they disappear after the first read....

you can also [forward](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding-to-another-controller) the request to another controller internally without actually sending a 301 to the browser.. ... that might be another solution you can play around with ...